# Self-generating buttons not persisting upon restarting GUI

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, button

I have a program creating self-generating buttons based on an entry, because the buttons aren't stored anywhere in the program they disappear after the GUI is restarted. I need these buttons to persist after termination of the GUI, but to still self generate every time the submit function is called. It's worth noting that there is a database in the full program storing f_name. I'm not sure how to pull out f_name from my database for each dataset or if I can create a function that will write these buttons into the program when they're initially generated.

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Button')
root.geometry('400x400')
#Entry & Label
f_name = Entry(root, width=30)
f_name.grid(row=0, column=1)
f_name_lbl = Label(root, text="First Name:")
f_name_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Retrieves f_name and generates a button at next highest row
def gen_button():
    auto_button = Button(button_frame, text=f_name.get())
    auto_button.pack(side="top")

submit_btn = Button(root, text="Submit:", command=gen_button)
submit_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, ipadx=100)

button_frame = Frame(root)
button_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
#Credit to Bryan Oakley for the auto_button.pack and the button_frame
```

Comment: Maybe try creating a list of the names submitted, and then use that to recreate the buttons. The advantage to doing this is that it can also be saved to a file, for later reference.

Comment: @SamMatzko Currently working on using your idea to create a dynamic array to store the f_name.get(), if I can get this working I believe you're correct. Will reply when I get it or don't

Comment: @SamMatzko Okay, I've played with this for a good little while and I'm not getting progress. From what I've read and tried, array and list don't have the ability to use a .get() to add to their list. This will be a dynamic database, so I don't have the ability to list its contents out. The only way I can think of incorporating this is if I could get a variable = f_name.get() and list.insert(0, variable) if != list[0]. I'll play around with that for a bit and see if you might catch something I'm not or if someone has a different idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into tkinter or python to automatically save and restore data for you, but the ability to save and restore data is a fundamental property of just about all programming languages. You just have to write the code to do it.

### Creating buttons from existing data

Let's start with a function that can take one or more strings and creates buttons. You already have a function like that, but this function needs to be given the strings rather than having it fetch the string from a widget.

```py
def add_buttons(*items):
    for item in items:
        auto_button = Button(button_frame, text=item)
        auto_button.pack(side="top")
```

With that, we can now pass in a list of strings that will get converted into buttons.

```
add_buttons("button one", "button two")
```

### Reading the buttons from a file

Next, we need to be able to read the list of strings from some sort of storage. The storage method is irrelevant for the purposes of this answer; the function simply needs to return a list of strings. In this case, we'll just read from a flat file. The strings could easily come from a database or web-based service.

```py
from pathlib import Path

def get_items(path):
    if path.exists():
        with open(path, "r") as f:
            data = f.read().strip().splitlines()
            return data
    return []

path = Path("buttons.txt")
items = get_items(path)
```

With those two functions, we have a way to read a list of strings and convert them into a series of buttons. With just a few extra lines of code we have a working program:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import tkinter as tk

def add_buttons(*items):
    for item in items:
        auto_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text=item)
        auto_button.pack(side="top")

def get_items(path):
    if path.exists():
        with open(path, "r") as f:
            data = f.read().strip().splitlines()
            return data
    return []

root = tk.Tk()
button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

path = Path("buttons.txt")
items = get_items(path)
add_buttons(*items)

root.mainloop()
```

If you hand-edit the file "buttons.txt" in your working directory to contain one or more lines of text, you'll get a button for each line of text.  For example, edit the file to contain the following:

```
button one
button two
button three
```

When you run your program you'll get something like this:

[image: screenshot of three buttons]

### Saving the button text to a file

The final piece of the puzzle is to be able to save the data to a file. It will look a lot like the function to create the buttons, only it needs to accept a list of items and write them to a file.

```py
def save_items(path, items):
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write("\n".join(items))
```

### Creating new buttons from an Entry widget

In your original code, you want to be able to create buttons by clicking another button and getting the text from an entry widget. You can create a new function that gets the text from the entry and then uses the other functions to both create the button and save the text.

```py
def submit():
    global items

    # get the text and append it to our global list of button text
    text = entry.get()
    items.append(text)

    # create the button
    add_buttons(text)

    # save the list of items
    save_items(path, items)
```

### Putting it all together

Here is the complete program. It's missing error checking, and probably shouldn't rely on global variables, but the point is to illustrate how to save and restore data using a file.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import tkinter as tk

def add_buttons(*items):
    for item in items:
        auto_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text=item)
        auto_button.pack(side="top")

def get_items(path):
    if path.exists():
        with open(path, "r") as f:
            data = f.read().strip().splitlines()
            return data
    return []

def save_items(path, items):
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write("\n".join(items))

def submit():
    global items

    # get the text and append it to our global list of button text
    text = entry.get()
    items.append(text)

    # create the button
    add_buttons(text)

    # save the list of items
    save_items(path, items)

root = tk.Tk()
button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
entry = tk.Entry(root)
submit = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit)

entry.pack(side="top")
submit.pack(side="top")
button_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

# initialize our list of buttons from a file
path = Path("buttons.txt")
items = get_items(path)
add_buttons(*items)

root.mainloop()
```

### Summary

This isn't the only way to solve the problem, but it illustrates the general pattern of creating functions to read the data, save the data, and display the data. You are free to reimplement those functions any way you see fit.